# How can I only remove the shipping method on the cart page, not on the checkout. woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I modified the `cart-shipping.php` to remove the shipping method.

But, when I delete the code to remove the shipping method, that also will remove the shipping method on the `checkout page`. How can I just delete the method on the cart and keep the shipping method on the checkout page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label',             
'bbloomer_remove_shipping_label', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_remove_shipping_label($label, $method) {
$new_label = preg_replace( '/^.+:/', '', $label );
return $new_label;
}
```

Comment: I added these code into `functions.php`, but nothing happen. Do it need to do something first?

Answer (score 0):

please antick first checkbox of calculations   [image]